# How to do aggregation with calculation in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

[image]

I have similar table with two columns, C2 will have multiple values . I need the output as

[image]

Condition for t2.c2 is If all the values in t1.C2 are <= 5, then 1 else 0, please advice what would be the best logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give desired result. First section has t1 table data, second section has t2 data based on logic requested.

```
with t1 as 
(select 'A10' as C1, 2 as C2 union all
select 'A10' as C1, 3 as C2 union all
select 'A10' as C1, 4 as C2 union all
select 'A10' as C1, 5 as C2 union all
select 'A10' as C1, 3 as C2 union all
select 'A10' as C1, 4 as C2 union all
select 'A10' as C1, 2 as C2 union all
select 'A10' as C1, 4 as C2 union all
select 'A10' as C1, 5 as C2 union all
select 'A10' as C1, 3 as C2 )

select C1 , if(MAX(C2) <=5,1,0) as C2
from t1 group by C1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option

```
select distinct C1, 
  if(logical_and(C2 <= 5) over(partition by C1), 1, 0) as C2
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]